# How do I print two kinds of lines one by one

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

I have used different for loops with functions in it to get the names and lastnames. I have coded and are able to print the following (these names all start on a new line):

```
Micheal
John
Mick
Neil
Phill 
Billy
Jackson
Lennon
Jagger
Young
Collins
Joel
```

How do I now make the program so that it prints it like this (also all names on a new line, last names on another line, Jackson is on line 2):

```
Micheal
Jackson
John
Lennon
Mick
Jagger
Neil
Young
Phill
Collins 
Billy
Joel
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I asked it like this because I thought it would be easy to answer and ir would be unnecessary to give a lot more information or my code. I will do it differently next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you question,
but if I do, you are asking for something like this:

```
names = ["Michael", "John"]
surnames=["Jackson" ,"Lennon"]
for i, j in names, surnames:
    print i
    print j
```

You could have a dictionary with corresponding first names and surnames as well.

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition, accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.